# Joining tables by dates is dropping dates I want to keep

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a date table [DateDim] that lists out all of the dates during a given month:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-03-01 |
| 2021-03-02 |
| 2021-03-03 |
| 2021-03-04 |
| 2021-03-05 |
| 2021-03-06 |

I am trying to join a table [PurchaseDays] that will only have some of the dates

| Date | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-02 | 7.17 |
| 2021-03-05 | 21.21 |
| 2021-03-06 | 13.87 |

And what I am trying to do is join the tables so I have an output that looks like this.  I would also be okay if the values were 0 instead of NULL.

| Date | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | NULL |
| 2021-03-02 | 7.17 |
| 2021-03-03 | NULL |
| 2021-03-04 | NULL |
| 2021-03-05 | 21.21 |
| 2021-03-06 | 13.87 |

The issue I keep running into is when I join the tables, when I do `Datedim.Date = PurchaseDays.Date` I only keep the dates from the PurchaseDays table, no matter what type of join I am using.

So is there a way to join only certain days onto a list that contains a full date range?

Right now my code looks like this

```
SELECT 
    Date
FROM 
    Datedim
LEFT JOIN
    PurchaseDays
        ON
    Datedim.Date = PurchaseDays.Date
WHERE
    Datedim.Date BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-06'
```

Comment: You forgot to include the code you have that isn't working.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu.  I've updated my question to include my code.

Comment: The query you added should work.  Either that's not the code you're running, or the `datedim` table is missing certain dates.  What does this give?  `SELECT date FROM Datedim WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-06'`?

Comment: It returns the list of dates that I have in my initial post.  And the query I posted is my actual query. If I change the date range, no matter how I join it I am getting only the dates from the purchase dates table.

Comment: This query should fail with " ambigious Date ".

Comment: @Ironicallylaughing - See if you can replicate your problem on https://dbfiddle.uk/ and link the example here.  Because so far what you've shown doesn't match up.  If the tables are as you say, and the SQL is as you say, you should get the results you want.  ***Something*** is not as you say *(or missing from what you say)*.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what changed.  But I just got your query to work.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to keep all the rows from `Datedim` so you need to put that first, then `LEFT JOIN` on to it.

```
SELECT
  Datedim.date,
  PurchaseDays.Balance
FROM
  Datedim
LEFT JOIN
  PurchaseDays
    ON Datedim.Date = PurchaseDays.Date
```

Just be careful that you don't add a `WHERE` clause that refers to the `PurchaseDays` table.  `WHERE` is applied ***after*** `JOIN`, and so will be reading `NULL`s and so rows that were ***kept*** by the `LEFT JOIN` can be ***excluded*** by the `WHERE` clause.

For example, this is wrong...

```
SELECT
  Datedim.date,
  PurchaseDays.Balance
FROM
  Datedim
LEFT JOIN
  PurchaseDays
    ON Datedim.Date = PurchaseDays.Date
WHERE
  PurchaseDays.Date BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-06'
```

But this is fine...

```
SELECT
  Datedim.date,
  PurchaseDays.Balance
FROM
  Datedim
LEFT JOIN
  PurchaseDays
    ON Datedim.Date = PurchaseDays.Date
WHERE
  Datedim.Date BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-06'
```